# Using information based on cache, browser history or/and cookies to build infographic/analysis

Tags: caching, cookies

Complete novice here!

I am trying to create a quick site which would look into people's cache, browser history or/and cookies to create a quick 'psych' analysis of that person.

So if I have any Angry Birds item on my search history, or cache etc, my analysis results would use that to say 'you play Angry bird, or you are just one angry bird.' kind of message..

Is this even possible...?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Not without having the user install some software or browser plugin.

Comment: what kind of browser plugin will this need..?